# VCLua library fault to load

Tags: lua, window

I have downloaded VCLua library [here](http://vclua.luaforge.net/tut01.html). I created new file named program.lua and typed there code that is in tutorial:

```
require "vcl"

mainForm = VCL.Form("mainForm")

mainForm.Caption = "My first VCLua application"
mainForm._= { position="podesktopcenter", height=400, width=600}

mainForm.onclosequery = "onCloseQueryEventHandler" 

function onCloseQueryEventHandler(Sender)
    return true -- the form can be closed
end

mainMenu = VCL.MainMenu(mainForm,"mainMenu")
mainMenu:LoadFromTable({
    {name="mmfile", caption="&File", 
        submenu={
            {name="mmOpen", caption="Open...", onclick="onMenuOpenClick", shortcut="Ctrl+O"}, 
            {caption="-",},
            {caption="Exit", onclick="onMenuExitClick", shortcut="Alt+F4"}, 
        }
    },
    {name="mmhelp", caption="&Help", RightJustify=true, 
        submenu =  {
            {caption="Help", shortcut="F1", checked=true},
            {caption="-",},
        }
    }
})

mainMenu:Find("mmhelp"):Add("mmAbout")._=  {caption="About", onclick="onMenuAboutClick", enabled=false}

function onMenuExitClick()
    mainForm:Close()
end

mainToolbar = VCL.ToolBar(mainForm,"mainToolbar")
mainToolbar:LoadFromTable({
    {name="mtbOpen", onclick="onMenuOpenClick"},
    {name="mtbExit", onclick="onMenuExitClick"},
})

mainToolbar:Find("mtbOpen").enabled=false

mainForm:ShowModal()

mainForm:Free()
```

But when i want to run it (i have both vcl.dll and vcl.so files in directory where lua interpreter is), it writes `lua: error loading module 'vcl' from file 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Programs\lua\vcl.dll':`. Stack trace dont say anything useful. So can anyone tell me, how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic libraries for Lua are usually compiled against Lua DLLs; you may get this error in a case when the dynamic library can't find the Lua DLLs it's linked against. You can see why/how it fails using a tool like [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), which can show you both what other DLLs your library depends on and also what run-time error you get when you load it (you can use "Profile" mode to see that).

Comment: It would say that i am missing dll. Okay, dependency walker didnt say anything useful, standard system libraries, and lua 5.1 dll, that is located in directory where vcl.dll is placed.

Comment: Ok i used profiler and output seems strange to me:
`DllMain(0x10000000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "VCL.DLL" returned 0 (0x0).` Can dll be... corputted? I have found following github repo: https://github.com/rmbishop/VCLua, but i cant build it myself (no delphi compiler)